# Cartoon where genius kid is trying to escape from an island and had lot of masks

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember seeing a cartoon on *Cartoon Network* where a kid is trying to escape from an island with a lot of people on it.  He is a science genius sort of kid and keeps trying to create things, but has now made friends on the island.  The cartoon had lot of masks, the kind of hawaiian masks in the introduction....

It had a volcano in it and was from about probably 10 years ago.

Comment: Sounds like Dexter's Laboratory.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like [Mike, Lu & Og](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike,_Lu_%26_Og). Og would be the genius that you're thinking of. Show aired until 2001 but I'm sure reruns ran for some time after so 10 years doesn't seem too far off.

I can see OP forgetting the other two characters, or not remembering them as main characters, but that would relate to the friends that Og made. Og and Lu were actually natives of the island while Mike was a foreign exchange student who, more or less, accidentally stumbled upon this island when trying to be sent to a tropical island. If you watch the [introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmz1diDfWMY) of the show you'll see the volcano almost instantly. The only thing I couldn't find a direct reference for were the masks, but I don't think it's too farfetched that there were episodes were some people were wearing masks on a tropical island with tribal natives.